# Updating Service from ASMX to WCF Service Problems!

Tags: wcf

The following is some old ASMX code which I need to convert to WCF service code

```
Dim cc As New System.Net.CredentialCache

        cc.Add(New System.Uri(url), "BASIC", New System.Net.NetworkCredential( _
                        userName, _
                        password, _
                        domain))
```

And here is my WCF code:

```
 myServiceInstance.Endpoint.Address = New EndpointAddress(url)
 Dim credentials As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain)
 myServiceInstance.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials
```

How do I set the AuthenticationType to BASIC in a WCF service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service host you can do this programatically using wsHttpBinding

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
    HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
```

If you want to do it via config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="UsernameWithTransport">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
<!-- Service Details Here -->
         </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```